# rails - select_tag default to blank when using map

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have my select_tag default to blank but i'm using a map

```
<%= select_tag "assignment[client_id]", options_for_select(@data.map{|d| ["#{d.first_name} #{d.last_name}",d.id]}, " ") %>
```

I know you can't use include_blank and you can't put " " to set it to blank. any ideas ?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rails provides the `select` helper method, which has a `:include_blank` option, use like:

```
<%= select("assignment", "client_id", @data.map { |d| ["#{d.first_name} #{d.last_name}", d.id] }, { :include_blank => true }) %>
```

See the [Rails' FormOptionsHelper#select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M002302) for more informations.

PS: OT: Maybe add a `def name; "#{first_name} #{last_name}" end` method to your model :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! im using form_for so need to use select_tag any other ideas ?

Comment: afaik, then you can just do `f.select(:client_id, @data..., :include_blank => true)`, at least that's how I use it my code, doesn't that work?